# AWS Kinesis Analytics - GROUP BY on stream

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I need some help on my AWS Kinesis Analytics function.

I have a stream which contains these datas :

```
hubId (Integer)
datetime (timestamp)
fid (varchar)
path (varchar)
```

I would like to aggregate these datas into another stream, to count the number of rows per hour (pageviews) and the number of distinct fid per hour (visitors), group by hubId.

Destination stream :

```
profilesite_id(Integer) = hubId from source stream
datetime (timestamp)
visitors (Integer)
pageviews (Integer)
```

So in MySQL, my function is like this:

```
SELECT hubId, CONCAT_WS(':', SUBSTR(datetime, 1, 13), '00:00') datetime, COUNT(*) pageviews, COUNT(DISTINCT(fid)) visitors
FROM tableStream
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY hubId, CONCAT_WS(':', SUBSTR(datetime, 1, 13), '00:00');
```

I tried to convert this request into Kinesis Analytics, but it's pretty hard (first time for me... sorry :) ).

- The CURDATE() function doesn't work in Kinesis
- The CONCAT_WS also

So currently I have this Kinesis Analytics function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "bore_agg" (profilsite_id SMALLINT, datetime TIMESTAMP, visitors INT, pageviews INT);

-- Create pump to insert into output 
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "bore_agg"

-- Select all columns from source stream
SELECT 
    SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."hubId" profilsite_id, 
    CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', TIMESTAMP_TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00', SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."datetime")) datetime, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."fid")) visitors, 
    COUNT(*) pageviews
FROM SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001
WHERE SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."datetime" >= CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', TIME_TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00', CURRENT_TIME))
GROUP BY 
    SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."hubId", 
    CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', TIMESTAMP_TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00', SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."datetime"));
```

But I have this error and I don't really understand what to do :

> There was an error in your SQL code There was an issue updating your
>   application. Error message: Failed SQL command: CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP
>   "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "bore_agg" SELECT
>   SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."hubId" profilsite_id,
>   CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', TIMESTAMP_TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:00:00', SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."datetime")) datetime,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT(SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."fid")) visitors, COUNT(*)
>   pageviews FROM SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001 WHERE
>   SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."datetime" >= CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('yyyy-MM-DD
>   hh:mm:ss', TIME_TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00', CURRENT_TIME)) GROUP BY
>   SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."hubId", CHAR_TO_TIMESTAMP('yyyy-MM-DD
>   hh:mm:ss', TIMESTAMP_TO_CHAR('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00',
>   SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001."datetime")). SQL error message: From line 9,
>   column 1 to line 11, column 120: **Cannot aggregate an infinite stream:
>   GROUP BY clause is not specified or does not contain any monotonic
>   expressions.**

Could anyone putting me in the right direction please ?

Thanks in advance :)

Thomas

Comment: Here is what I have just been learning.. basically think of Kinesis Analytics GROUP BY as a kind of blocker. When you GROUP BY it needs to know when the group ends. For example, 1,1,1,2,2,3. The group by can, for lack of a better word, "release" the `1's` group when it see that the next value is `2`. So if you were to `GROUP BY STEP(ROWTIME BY INTERVAL '1' SECOND)` you would get a row every second. If you `GROUP BY STEP(ROWTIME BY INTERVAL '1' HOUR)` you would get a row every hour, AKA when the timestamp changes from `00:01:00T00-00-00` to `00:02:00T00-00-00`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, since the (only) response from Adam here. So, just in case it helps someone, as Adam points out and if you think about it, the Data Analytics stream can be an "infinite" input. Therefore, you need to tell where to stop; i.e. "aggregate the data for the last minute or hour of my stream". So, in this example (code below), it will aggregate the incoming data of the stream, until the specified minute or hour.

Note: bear in mind you first need to create a STREAM, with the same structure (number of columns and data types returned), and then run the "INSERT-SELECT" into the new stream, by creating a PUMP which will be the process scanning the incoming data and returning the results (to be inserted into the STREAM in the initial step).

Examples:

```
-- ** Aggregate (COUNT, AVG, etc.) + Tumbling Time Window **
-- Performs function on the aggregate rows over a 10 second tumbling window for a specified column. 
--          .----------.   .----------.   .----------.              
--          |  SOURCE  |   |  INSERT  |   |  DESTIN. |              
-- Source-->|  STREAM  |-->| & SELECT |-->|  STREAM  |-->Destination
--          |          |   |  (PUMP)  |   |          |              
--          '----------'   '----------'   '----------'               
-- STREAM (in-application): a continuously updated entity that you can SELECT from and INSERT into like a TABLE
-- PUMP: an entity used to continuously 'SELECT ... FROM' a source STREAM, and INSERT SQL results into an output STREAM
-- Create output stream, which can be used to send to a destination
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM (ingest_time TIMESTAMP, vendorid int, count_vs_time int);
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"

-- Query 1):
-- Group by VendorID over the last 60 seconds of the stream.
SELECT STREAM STEP("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME BY INTERVAL '60' SECOND) AS ingest_time, "vendorid", COUNT(*)
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001" 
GROUP BY STEP("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME BY INTERVAL '60' SECOND), "vendorid";


--Query 2)
-- Group by VendorID and count, over the last hour of the stream.
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM (hour_range TIMESTAMP, vendorid int, count_last_hr int);
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
SELECT STREAM FLOOR("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME TO HOUR) AS hour_range, "vendorid", COUNT(*) as count_last_hr
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001" 
GROUP BY FLOOR("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME TO HOUR), "vendorid";
```

HTH.

Carlos.